# Get different theming in bootstrap in different views

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, modularization

I would like to theme pages with bootstrap but in some of the pages I would like to theme only the buttons and leave the input fields like they are, while in others I would like to do it the other way around and only theme the input fields and not the buttons.

I would like to be able to write something like that

In page1:

@import input-theming.css
... use default styling for buttons

In page 2:

@import button-theming.css
... use default styling for inputs

I have already thought about modularizing my [custom.scss](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/#importing) in components such that I in each component I theme a different part, like inputs, buttons, tables , ... etc. But then I would have to create a custom.scss file for each combination of those modules which seems complicated.

What I would like is a way to get back to the default behavior of some parts of bootstrap although I themed them differently in the custom.scss. Is that possible without generating different custom.scss files that theme only different parts of bootstrap?

Comment: Please clarify the question with code you've tried so far or some visualization of what you expect.

Comment: Okay I added some code 

Answer (score 0):

SASS allows you to nest imports. Therefore, you could use a parent class for each "theme" (combination of customizations) and then add the appropriate theme CSS class to the HTML parent container of each page (html,body,.container etc...). This allows you to keep all of the SASS overrides/changes in one `custom.scss` file.

```
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/variables";

.theme-1 {
    /* change the button style */
    .btn-primary {
        @include button-variant(green, green);
    }
}

.theme-2 {
    /* change the input style */
    $input-bg: #ddd;
    @import "bootstrap/forms"
}

@import "bootstrap"
```

HTML Page 1 (custom buttons)

```
<body class="theme-1">    
    <div class="container py-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="addon">Button</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

HTML Page 2 (custom inputs)

```
<body class="theme-2">    
    <div class="container py-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="addon">Button</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/53aqV0BaMt)

Comment: I tried to do it as you suggested but there is a problem with the importing bootstrap/variables. Obviously this file does map $input-bg to $input-focus-bg. So in order to get the same results as when I only declared variables in the top level code, I need to import bootstrap/variables after I declared $input-bg. On the other hand I need to import it before @import "bootstrap/forms". That means I need to include it into the theme-2 class. But this does not seem to be allowed: https://www.codeply.com/go/WThSLW21n8

Comment: You wouldn't import the variables after.. you'd import them before! They're needed to reference the variables you're redefining,

Comment: so what happens to the mapping?